# How to fix 'Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)...'

Tags: reactjs

Received the following error:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
> it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named
> imports.'

I tried to rearrange `export default App` in different lines of the `App.js` file but the error persists.

Please let me know how I can fix this.

**App:**

```
const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    hits: [],
    page: null,
    isError: false,
    isLoading: false
  });
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");

  const onInitialSearch = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (query === "") {
      return;
    }
    fetchStories(query, 0);
  };

  const onPaginatedSearch = (event) => fetchStories(query, state.page + 1);

  const fetchStories = (value, page) =>
    fetch(getHackerNewsUrl(value, page))
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((result) => onSetResult(result, page))
      .catch(this.onSetError);

  const onSetResult = (result, page) =>
    page === 0
      ? setState(applySetResult(result))
      : setState(applyUpdateResult(result));

  const onSetError = () => setState(applySetError);

  return (
    <div className="page">
      <div className="interactions">
        <form type="submit" onSubmit={onInitialSearch}>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="query"
            value={query}
            onChange={(event) => setQuery(event.target.value)}
          />
          <button type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>

      <AdvancedList
        list={state.hits}
        isError={state.isError}
        page={state.page}
        onPaginatedSearch={onPaginatedSearch}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: error is with `AdvancedList`. you are using a library that has no longer support (last update 2 years ago)  to create `AdvancedList` with `compose` function.

Comment: @buzatto thank you, i will migrate to using hooks instead.